# Jackson JSON serialization inclusion to ignore only null fields and empty collections

Tags: jackson, jackson-modules, jackson-databind

We have recently moved from Jackson json 2.8.2 to 2.9.4 and we're seeing major changes in the behavior. We are using JDK 1.8.

Earlier we set the Serialization inclusion as NON_DEFAULT at object mapper level and all wasworking fine.

Now after changed to 2.9.2, NON_DEFAULT is ignoring all default values like boolean false, integer 0,.... This is breaking our test cases.

Our requirement is to ignore only null fields and blank fields like returning as [].

But we still want to **not ignore** empty strings for example test = ""

We tried non_empty, non_absent all ignoring every field (null, [], "").

Can you suggest how we can customize the serialization behavior to meet our requirement? Let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways:

1. Specify different setting for type `String.class`: look at `ObjectMapper.configOverrides(String.class)`; there's a setter for `JsonInclude.Value` (type which has various factory methods). You can set that as `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL` (or `ALWAYS`), even if default is something else
2. Register custom serializer for `String`, override/redefine its `isEmpty(SerializerProvider, String)` method NOT to consider empty String as `empty` for purposes of exclusion